# JPA/Hibernate: save an Entity that holds list of Entities that hold a 2D array of objects in a object hierarchy

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist my Game class, structured as follows:

- An class Game, which holds a list of Boards
- The Board Entity class a 2D array of Fields, representing a playing board.
- The Field class is abstract and has concrete subclasses such as Floor, Goal and Wall.

What I would like to have is a One-to-many relationship beween Game and Board Entities, and the Fields in the Board class as an embedded property. To embed this I'd like to write my own mapping code to turn the 2D array into a String of symbols representing the fields, but if that's not possible then I'd save the hierarchy using the single-table strategy.

I'm still learning JPA/Hibernate so there's a bit too much going on at once for me to fully grasp how to tackle this.

This is what I've tried:

### Implementing an AttributeConverter for Board

I learned that this is not possible because AttributeConverters cannot be used for relationship attributes (JPA spec).

### Implementing an AttributeConverter for Field[][], and making it an Embedded property

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Getter
    private List<Board> boards = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Board {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="game_id")
    private Game game;

    @Embedded
    @Convert(converter = FieldsConverter.class, attributeName = "field")
    private Field[][] fields;
```

with FieldsConverter being

```
@Converter
public class FieldsConverter implements AttributeConverter<Field[][], String> {
```

IntelliJ already gives a "Embedded atribute type should not be Field[][]" error, running results in a weird ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (see https://pastebin.com/ZVbCGaGA for full stacktrace).

### Writing the JDBC mapping myself

I also started writing a BoardRepository myself, in which I manually did the mapping of the Fields attribute, but then I remembered that then I'd probably have no managed relationship between Game and Board, or the lazy loading that JPA would provide, so I stopped before I was fully ready.

One thing I read that comes close to a solution is this: https://vladmihalcea.com/multidimensional-array-jpa-hibernate/, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to an Embedded attribute and the object actually being part of an object hierarchy.

Could anyone please give me some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you say you want to 'write my own mapping code to turn the 2D array into a String of symbols', why do you feel you need `@Embedded`, then?

Comment: Also, do you need the `Field` data to be queryable (your proposed solution with a string of symbols suggests you don't)? If not, the simplest solution would be to simply use a wrapper class (sth like `FieldArray`) and make it `Serializable`. You'll need to make the entire `Field` class hierarchy `Serializable` as well, of course

Comment: @crizzis I guess you're right about the Embedded and the 2D-array-to-String construction. I'm probably mixing things up too much. The fields don't have to be queryable, they're always tied to a Board.

Comment: @crizzis By the FieldArray, you mean creating a list of FieldArrays to emulate the 2D array, or the FieldArray would hold the 2D array itself? I'm not a big fan of storing binary data in the db, that's why I was thinking about the mapping to a String.

Comment: The second option. And, if you don't want binary format, then IMHO your original approach should work as well; just strip the `@Embedded` annotation, it does not apply in this scenario. I suggested `Serializable` merely because it's an out-of-the-box solution

Comment: @crizzis I removed the Embedded annotation. I save a game with a board when bootstrapping and when I debug I get into the FieldsConverter, but still it crashes with a "NotSerializableException: be.harm.sokoban.game.board.Floor". So after the Converter it still wants to serialize the Board. Documentation for the Convert annotation states: "The Convert annotation may be applied to a basic attribute or to an element collection of basic type ". My Field isn't a basic type, so maybe that's the problem. But is there a way to get around that?

Comment: That might be the issue. I'd try introducing a wrapper class for the array